# How to order by string, Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-order-by, rails-activerecord

So I've got @cake.type, which can be either "Primo", "Multilayered", "Decorative", "On Sale", "Basic"`

I want to organize the list the Cakes in that order. So all the "Primo" cakes at the top, followed by all the "Multilayered" cakes next etc. Each type of cake should be further listed by "created_at" (oldest created cake first).

```
@cakes = []
@cakes << @store.cakes.where(type: "Primo").order(created_at: :desc) 
@cakes << @store.cakes.where(type: "Multilayered").order(created_at: :desc) 
@cakes << @store.cakes.where(type: "Decorative").order(created_at: :desc) 
@cakes << @store.cakes.where(type: "On Sale").order(created_at: :desc) 
@cakes << @store.cakes.where(type: "Basic", "Basic").order(created_at: :desc)
```

there a way to do it with one query?

... maybe:

```
cake_eater_nom = []

c = @store.cakes
primo_cakes = c.where(type: "Primo").order(created_at: :desc)
cake_eater_nom << primo_cakes
multilayered_cakes = c.where(type: "Multilayered").order(created_at: :desc) 
cake_eater_nom << multilayered_cakes
decorative_cakes = c.where(type: "Decorative").order(created_at: :desc) 
cake_eater_nom << decorative_cakes
on_sale_cakes = c.where(type: "On Sale").order(created_at: :desc)
cake_eater_nom << on_sale_cakes
basic_cakes = c.where(type: "Basic").order(created_at: :desc)
cake_eater_nom << basic_cakes
```

Comment: You should probably do a `where(type: [ ... ])` which does an `IN (...)` in the SQL side, meaning you do one query, and then sort the records you get back. Ideally you have some kind of sort hint column in the database, but barring that, you can sort by the `index_of` value in this list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are already on Ruby on Rails 7.0, then you can use [`in_order_of`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42061) like this:

```
types = ['Primo', 'Multilayered', 'Decorative', 'On Sale', 'Basic']

@cakes = @store.cakes
               .where(type: types)
               .in_order_of(:type, types) # sort by type (from list) frist 
               .order(:created_at)        # then by created_at (oldest first)
```

Comment: TIL - nice one!

Answer (score 2):

You can add an additional field to store the order you need or write a custom condition using `CASE WHEN` + `created_at`.

```rb
order_sql = Arel.sql(
  "CASE WHEN type = 'Primo' THEN 0 " \
    "WHEN type = 'Multilayered' THEN 1 " \
    "WHEN type = 'Decorative' THEN 2 " \
    "WHEN type = 'On Sale' THEN 3 " \
    'ELSE 4 END, created_at'
)
@cakes = @store.cakes.order(order_sql)
```

Comment: thank you. ... never even seen raw SQL before

Answer (score 1):

You can map types with integers and order by them like this

```rb
@cakes = @store.cakes.order(
  "CASE type WHEN 'Primo' THEN 1 WHEN 'Multilayered' THEN 2 WHEN 'Decorative' THEN 3 WHEN 'On Sale' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END"
  "created_at DESC"
)
```

You can also define some scope this way in the model and apply it

```
# In the Cake model
scope :order_by_type_and_created_at_desc, ->() do
  order(
    <<~SQL,
      CASE type
      WHEN 'Primo' THEN 1
      WHEN 'Multilayered' THEN 2
      WHEN 'Decorative' THEN 3
      WHEN 'On Sale' THEN 4
      ELSE 5
      END
    SQL
    "created_at DESC"
  )
end

# Apply that scope
@cakes = @store.cakes.order_by_type_and_created_at_desc
```

Another option is to keep in the database that types as integers and use enum

```
# Enum
enum type: { primo: 1, multilayered: 2, decorative: 3, on_sale: 4, basic: 5 }

# Scope
scope :order_by_type_and_created_at_desc, ->() { order(type: :asc, created_at: :desc) }
```

NB: `type` is reserved word that used for STI (single table inheritance)

Comment: and now i've learned scopes are custom queries defined in the model, I appreciate that.